# Onclick display hidden fields without Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a Javascript function which is used to display and hide the content.

```
function hiddenfield() {
    document.getElementById('previousName').addEventListener('change', function () {
        if (document.getElementById('previousName').checked) {
            document.getElementById('prevname').style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('prevname').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }, false);
}
```

In the view,

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsPreviousName, new { id = "previousName", onclick = "if(this.checked){hiddenfield()}" }) <label for="previousName">Select if you have previous name</label>

<div style="display:none;" id="prevname">
<label for="pfname">Previous Name</label>
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PreviousFName, new { id = "pfname" })
</div>
```

So my problem is that if JS is enabled it works fine, but I need to make it work without JS as well.
So, can anyone please suggest me how can I achieve this if Javascript is disabled in browser?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: *"...but I need to make it work without JS as well."* Then don't tag your question `javascript` (or `jquery`). Tag it `asp.net` or whatever you're using.

Comment: The only way to fake this working without javascript is to reload the page and use a server-side language to determine what fields to show/hide. It is not possible to do this client-side if JavaScript is disabled.

Comment: I am interested to know why you need it to work without JS.

Comment: @otherDewi: Yeah, given that ~98% of the browsing public have JS enabled...

Answer (score 2):

This is actually possible with CSS3. Assuming the following markup:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="previousName"><label for="previousName">Select if you have previous name</label>
<div style="display:none;" id="prevname">
    <label for="pfname">Previous Name</label>
    <input>
</div>
```

This should work on browsers supporting all the wizardry it uses (attribute selector, `:checked` pseudo-class and the general sibling selector `~`):

```css
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #prevname { 
    display: block !important; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4y3HT/

---

EDIT: As T.J. Crowder pointed out, `#previousName:checked ~ #prevname` would be a better selector.

Answer (score 2):

I can't picture your actual HTML from what you've quoted, but depending on your structure, With modern browsers, you can do this with CSS's `:checked` pseudo-class.

For instance, if the actual HTML looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="previousName">
<div id="prevname">...</div>
```

...then this CSS will do it on modern browsers:

```
#prevname {
    display: none;
}

#previousName:checked ~ #prevname {
    display: block;
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/UBaBimI/1/edit) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/UBaBimI/1/edit)

That's using a sibling combinator, but there are other options. The key thing is to ensure that `:checked` is supported on your target browsers.

On older browsers, you have two choices:

1. Use JavaScript
2. Refresh the page from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can not modify the DOM (show / hide items) without JavaScript!

Comment: That's not entirely true.

Comment: then explain to me how to modify the DOM without JavaScript please... http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/intro.html

Comment: There's a difference between showing/hiding items and modifying the DOM, see my answer for the former.

Comment: You can actually modify the DOM using CSS pseudo-elements (like `:before`).

Comment: Hide/show isn't modifying the DOM per say but modifying the user's view of the DOM. You can quite readily do so with CSS3 manipulation and a little bit of planning.